# Java current thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm confused about what is the current thread during the execution of a multithreaded program.

```
public class CurrentThread {

public static void main(String[] args) {
            // FROM HERE: will always be "main-thread" the current thread ?
    CurrentThread currentThread = new CurrentThread();
    currentThread.testCurrentThread();
            // TO HERE         
}

private void testCurrentThread() {
    // some other threads starts...
    AThread athread = new AThread();
    athread.start();
    // some other threads starts...
}

class AThread extends Thread {

    public AThread() {
        setName("thread-a");
    }

    public void run() {
        // FROM HERE: will always be thread-a the current thread during finish the run method ?
                    // some process
                    // TO HERE...
    }
}
```

}

Suppose that launches multiple threads before and after start the thread AThread:

1. When you are inside the main method, whenever you call Thread.currentThread() will be "main-thread"?
2. When you are inside the run method of AThread, whenever you call Thread.currentThread() will be "a-thread"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In short: 1) yes 2) the thread of the instance of `AThread`.

Comment: Thank you luiggi, I'm confused if the threads are not interfering with each other in run method or main method.

Comment: No, the threads don't interfere with each other. Note that they can share the same data (e.g. `List<SomeObject> someObjectList`) and process it in parallel.

Comment: Yeah, the threads can share the same data !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> currentThread: Returns a reference to the currently executing thread
>   object.

So when you are in your main method, that is your main thread and when you are in run method of AThread, then that is your a-thread.

Comment: It won't be the a-thread directly. If you have two instances of `AThread` and start them, they will be in different threads.

Comment: Also note that if multiple instances of AThread are running they will all have the same name (which is bad if you ever have to debug it)

Comment: @LucaTettamanti That's a valid point, having the same name is not a good idea. But I believe the questionner has written this raw code to get an answer to his confusion. So we should be lenient towards the coding correctness here

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are unclear about the distinction of "main thread" and "current thread".  First, the main thread is the thread that defines the context of your application; when the main thread ends, the application is (supposed to) end as well.

"Current thread" can be relative; you can have any number of threads running simultaneously--that's the point of threads--but "current thread" can mean "the thread of execution we're talking about now", or it can mean the Thread object which you get a reference to by calling the *static* method, as previously mentioned--that means "this thread, the path of execution I'm a step of".  If you call the currentThread() method in your main class or the thread in which your main class is running, you'll get a reference to the main thread--the thread controlling the lifecycle of the application (this is drastically oversimplified).  If you call currentThread() from any code that is running as a consequence of being part of or called by the run method of an object that extends thread, you get a reference to that instance of that object.  This is essentially the long way of saying what Juned said above.

Additionally, I humbly submit that you may be mixing languages; *CurrentThread* is a class in C# but not in Java.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Ben. Yeah, you understood my question correctly. I was confusing about threads interfering with each other in run method or main method, I thought that at some point could become a-thread the current thread within the main method (because I threw it) or at some point could  become main-thread the current thread within AThread's run method, but is it not possible, I'm right?

Comment: Each thread is a different object; the run method is like any other method, it applies to the instance from which it is being called.  I'm not sure I follow what you're asking here.  If an exception thrown in one thread will only be handled (or ignored) in that thread--exceptions do not cross thread boundaries.  If an exception causes the main thread to exit prematurely, threads spawned by the main thread can be orphaned and continue to run in the jvm.

Comment: I'm sorry, i meant (because i ran instead of "I threw it")

Comment: Ahh.  No, the main or primary thread is always the main thread.  I suppose you could contrive to make a secondary thread the main thread, but that would be deeper than the matter at hand.  When you invoke AThread's run(), it's invoked *from* the main thread, and is therefore secondary.  "thread-a" is the current thread from the perspective of code run from that instance of AThread's run() method.  Also, sorry about the C#/Java comment, I missed the outermost class name :/